# create reamore Button in angular with javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to get all the tags that have the class `containtText` back to me and I can find that tag value more than 300 characters and use continue for value . . .

But when I use this code:

```
<div class=" col-md-12 col-xl-12 col-sm-12 col-xl-12 col-lg-12 p-0">
<div class="row m-auto topbar col-md-12 col-xl-12 col-sm-12 col-xl-12 col-lg-12 p-3 mb-3">
    <span (click)="close()">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </span>
</div>
<div class=" mian-content form-inline content col-md-12 col-xl-12 col-sm-12 col-xl-12 col-lg-12 pt-2 pb-3">
    <div *ngFor="let item of globalModel;let i=index"
        class="form-group justify-content-start col-md-12 col-xl-12 col-sm-12 col-xl-12 col-lg-12 pt-2">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
            <label><strong>{{item.name | translate }} :</strong></label>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!item.isDate && !item.isBoolean && !item.isImage" class="showMore col-md-9 col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-12 col-lg-9 containtText">
            <label class="lbl">
                <span  class="spanArea">
                    {{item.value}}
                    <span class="">
                        <button mat-button (click)="FindLenghtString(item.value,i)" color="accent">Accent</button>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </label>

        </div>
        <div *ngIf="item.isBoolean" class=" col-md-9 col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-12 col-lg-9 containtText">
            <label class="lbl" *ngIf="item.value && !item.isDate">
                <span> <i class="fa fa-check-circle ic-green"></i></span>
            </label>
            <label class="lbl" *ngIf="!item.value && !item.isDate">
                <span> <i class="fa fa-ban ic-red"></i> </span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="item.isImage" class=" col-md-9 col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-12 col-lg-9 containtText">
            <label class="lbl" *ngIf="item.value && !item.isDate">
                <span (click)="openDialog(item.value)" class="show-img-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    {{'POST.PREVIEW' | translate}}
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="item.isDate" class=" col-md-9 col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-12 col-lg-9 containtText">
            <label class="lbl"
                *ngIf="item.isDate && lang=='fa'"><span>{{item.value | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'}}</span></label>
            <label class="lbl" *ngIf="item.isDate && lang!='fa'"><span>{{ item.value | jalali }}</span> </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ts :**

```
   Elipses(): void {
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('containtText'));
  }
```

it show me :

`HTMLCollection []`

and that value :

[image: Value]

but when i need to get Value of `2` it show me the `undefined`

```
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('containtText')['2']);
```

**how can i get value `2` and change that ?????**

Comment: You need to pass the number `2` instead of the string `'2'`. Although, Why are you doing this in the first place? You say you want to change the value after accessing it. This will increase the risks of causing issues with Angular since you are directly manipulating the DOM. Try a pure Angular solution instead.

Comment: @nash11 i using the number but still show me `undefined`

Comment: Can you try to call the function `Elipses` after the view is created? `setTimeout(()=>this.Elipses());` inside `ngOnInit`. Also, I think it is better to use small letters in function names.

Comment: @John thank you . i use my code in AfterViewInit and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to call the function `Elipses()` after the view is created?
I suggested the following in a comment

```
ngOnInit(){
  setTimeout(()=>this.Elipses()); 
}
```

However, I understand that you made it work by putting it inside AfterViewInit instead.

Answer (score -1):

First, I would not use jQuery or plain JavaScript when I have Angular :D

Second, ['2'] this is an index, so why '2'? :D

A simple solution in Angular:
Page:

```
<div>
  {{text}}
</div>
<button (click)="showText()>{{buttonName}}</button>
```

Component:

```
text = string;
fullText = "Really long text";
buttonName = "Show more";

ngOnInit(){
  text = fullText.substring(0, 5);
}

showText(){
  if(text.length === 5){
    text = fullText;
    buttonName= "Show less";
  } else {
    text = fullText.substring(0, 5);
    buttonName = "Show more";
  }
}
```

Comment: This shoudl be a comment

Comment: @Maryannah Is it better now?

Comment: @Maryannah I think it's related as I'm giving an alternative

Comment: @NikNik Yeah sure.